# Searching in ASP.NET CORE API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

Can u please help me?

I've project in ASP.NET CORE API where is a database of exams. I need filter it by class. For example: I have a list of exams for whole school and i want to display JSON for only one class exams.

I wrote code from: Microsoft Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but my Visual Studio didn't recognised "*GetByNameSubstring*". What can I do?

```
//GET: api/authors/search?namelike=th
    [HttpGet("Search")]
    public IActionResult Search(string namelike)
    {
        var result = _context.GetByNameSubstring(namelike);
        if (!result.Any())
        {
            return NotFound(namelike);
        }
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

[my code in VS2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOVbb.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not paste code as an image, but rather as text.

Comment: @citronas Ahh, thank you. I've added code in text.

Comment: What does `GetByNameSubstring` do ?

Comment: This function may search namelike string in specified culomn in my databse ( _context ) and add this rows to listview.

Answer (score 1):

The method `GetByNameSubstring(string nameSubstring)` is not a built in method; it's a method defined in the `Authors` class of the sample. If you want that method, you will have to add it, or extend your `_context` class.

The implementation is in the [sample code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/ebd9eca8c15d90eb9ee42de446e1fbfc421923bc/aspnetcore/web-api/advanced/formatting/3.0sample/Controllers/AuthorsController.cs#L95):

```cs
public List<Author> GetByNameSubstring(string nameSubstring)
{
  return List()
    .Where(a =>
      a.Name.IndexOf(nameSubstring, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
      .ToList();
}
```